# PHP POST request with multipart/form-data broken after certain inputs

Tags: php, forms, http-post, multipartform-data

I have a strange problem suddenly occuring on my webserver. I am posting forms to PHP and with a certain amount of inputs the $_POST array is empty and it seems that the input stream in not read completly.

```
<?php

var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));

print_r($_POST);

?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="blub" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub1" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo1"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub2" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo2"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub3" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo3"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub4" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo4"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub5" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo5"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub6" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo6"  value="abc">


<input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="blub" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub1" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo1"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub2" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo2"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub3" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo3"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub4" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo4"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub5" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo5"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub6" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo6"  value="abc">

<input type="text" name="blub7" value="12345">
<input type="text" name="foo7"  value="abc">


<input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

The first form is working properly, the second breaks with the following output:

```
string(118) "daryIaQvu0q5CBO86f9U Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo7" abc ------WebKitFormBoundaryIaQvu0q5CBO86f9U-- " Array ( )
```

I am unaware of any changes to the code, so it might have occured with some PHP updates or similar.

I checked a lot of settings, and the phpinfo settings are as follows:

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
enable_post_data_reading    On  On
file_uploads    On  On
max_execution_time  60  60
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 200 200
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    128M    128M
output_buffering    4096    4096
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   128M    128M
upload_max_filesize 128M    128M
variables_order GPCS    GPCS
```

Any suggestions what else to check? It seems that only a fixed amount of the input stream can be read, because changing the length of the submitted values changes the truncated part of the input stream.

Comment: what is the difference between the two forms? aside from the 2 extra input they are exactly the same. it doesn't make sense that the first one would work and the second one wouldn't. there's something you're not telling us. also, why are you using the `enctype` attribute in your forms? that's for uploading files, you don't need it for this.

Comment: This is the most simplified version I could break the problem down to. That is exactly it. I submit the first form and $_POST is correctly populated. I submit the second one, it does not work. The enctype is set, because in the original form where the problem first occured files are being uploaded, but it does not seem to be related to the files (other than that files exceed the input stream much quicker)

Comment: does it occur in all browsers, or just one?

Comment: your example works with out a problem here so you really need to post the code that's giving an error

Comment: Please visit this link http://www.conframe.de/form.php it is where this form is currently running. It is the complete code and since this causes the error already, I don't know what else to post. The actual example is using ExtJs to build a complex form and I cannot realy post that code here...

Comment: @PhilippDobrigkeit the link you posted works fine. it is not showing the results you explained. it shows all inputs on both forms.

Comment: The problem is not that inputs are not shown. The problem is when submitting the forms, that the POST variable is empty on the second form, which can be seen on top of both forms. I guess it is some kind of PHP or Apache configuration that has changed and now goes haywire

Comment: The problem seems to be with the size of the request transmitted. E.g. with Firefox both forms are not working and the output from php://input for the second form starts somewhere around "blub5" with IE, Safari, Chrome the output of php://input starts around "foo7".  The difference seems to be the length of the multipart separator added by the browser. So what I am experiencing is that POST data is read until a certain point and then something happens which leaves me with empty $_POST. The remaining data can be read with php://input but the beginning is already missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
string(118) "daryIaQvu0q5CBO86f9U Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo7" abc ------WebKitFormBoundaryIaQvu0q5CBO86f9U-- " Array ( )
```

here is the problem.  Look at your quotes, some are ending and some are not. You have quotes inside quotes?!?

Comment: That is the output that is generated by reading the input stream. I am not transmitting that data manually

Comment: Why do you have to seperate forms going to the same php file? Can we see form.php  i think you issue is there.  The rest looks correct. Many try ajax?

Comment: Your settings are the same as mine and i was able to send 100 char in 20 fields.

Comment: Also what data are you sending? Try it with out form encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out what the problem was. Moving the site to a new server fixed the problem. Thank you and sorry for everyone that I could not post a real solution.